# Android Maps Library V2 zoom controls custom position

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

How can i customize the position of the builtin zoom controls in a GoogleMap V2 ?

There are a lot of questions related to this topic for the Version 1 of Google Maps library.

[Placing Zoom Controls in a MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263507/placing-zoom-controls-in-a-mapview)

[How to reposition built-in zoom controls in MapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035347/how-to-reposition-built-in-zoom-controls-in-mapview)

[How to layout zoom Control with setBuiltInZoomControls(true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768097/how-to-layout-zoom-control-with-setbuiltinzoomcontrolstrue)

However, i wasn't able to find any questions in relation to the V2 of the library.

In the V2, there's no method

```
(LinearLayout) mapView.getZoomControls();
```

all the previously mentioned questions becomes obsolete.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might find [GoogleMap.setPadding()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) useful (added in September 2013).

```
map.setPadding(leftPadding, topPadding, rightPadding, bottomPadding);
```

From the API docs:

> This method allows you to define a visible region on the map, to signal to the map that portions of the map around the edges may be obscured, by setting padding on each of the four edges of the map. Map functions will be adapted to the padding. For example, the zoom controls, compass, copyright notices and Google logo will be moved to fit inside the defined region, camera movements will be relative to the center of the visible region, etc.

Also see the [description of how padding works in GoogleMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_padding).

Answer (score 26):

Yes, you can change position of **ZoomControl** and **MyLocation** button with small hack.
In my sample I have **SupportMapFragment**, which is inflated from xml layout.

View ids for ZoomControl and MyLocation button:

```
ZoomControl id = 0x1
MyLocation button id = 0x2
```

Code to update ZoomControl position:

```
// Find map fragment
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

// Find ZoomControl view
View zoomControls = mapFragment.getView().findViewById(0x1);

if (zoomControls != null && zoomControls.getLayoutParams() instanceof RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) {
    // ZoomControl is inside of RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) zoomControls.getLayoutParams();

    // Align it to - parent top|left
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    // Update margins, set to 10dp
    final int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
}
```

Comment: How can you ensure mapFragment.getView().findViewById(0x1); will always return the RelativeLayout with the zoom controls in it? As far as i know, that's usually a random integer generated by the android tools when they generate the R class. Am i missing something?

Comment: Because they are explicitly do ZoomControl.setId(1) and MyLocationButton.setId(2). So it should work fine, until they change ids. And there is also a third control with 0x3, but I'm not sure what it is for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though, i will keep the accepted answer because this is a hack, and not backed up by documentation.

Comment: I'm using the construction `GoogleMap gMap2 = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapViewAPI2)).getMap();` and couldn't determine how to access the mapFragment you referenced.  Can you advise?  Thanks!

Comment: Your map fragment is : `SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapViewAPI2);` If you need GoogleMap object you can then do: `GoogleMap gMap2 = mapFragment.getMap();`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for guidance on the map fragment.  I just +1'd you.

Comment: This is insanely fragile. These values can change with any Maps V2 release. Please simply hide the built-in zoom controls and add your own.

Comment: Hi vovkab, is it possible to reposition (i.e 50 dip below) the Compass button of map v2? If possible please give a response.

Comment: Even though it's a hack, it's an amazing one nonetheless. Kudos!
BTW what would be the ID for the Compass?

Comment: @vovkab adding if you wanna align at center vertical try it works for me
`( ( LinearLayout ) zoomControls ).setGravity( Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL );`

Comment: Although fragile, amazing solution. One problem: it works just great for zooming controls, but it does not work for my location button. It stretches and covers all the fragment (like it were aligned to the 4 corners). I've even tried to create new LayourParams but it keeps doing the same :(

Comment: In fact, using `params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP)` and `params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);` and adding aligns to bottom and left does the trick, but `removeRule`is only available from SDK 17, which sucks.

Comment: Just to add Toolbar Id = 0x3

Comment: MapView currently do not support Left and Right like ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT and in setMargin. Instead use Start and End like ALIGN_PARENT_START and params.setMarginStart(margin)

Answer (score 1):

I use MapFragment not SupportMapFragment:

```
import android.util.TypedValue;
```

in onCreate

```
    // Find map fragment

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);

    int ZoomControl_id = 0x1;
    int MyLocation_button_id = 0x2;

    // Find ZoomControl view
    View zoomControls = mapFragment.getView().findViewById(ZoomControl_id);

    if (zoomControls != null && zoomControls.getLayoutParams() instanceof RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) {
        // ZoomControl is inside of RelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) zoomControls.getLayoutParams();

        // Align it to - parent top|left
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        // Update margins, set to 10dp
        final int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I needed. Other solutions on SO are either deprecated or didn't work for me. I just had to use `zoomControls.setPadding(20,0,0,20);` instead because `margin` didn't work, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

Navigation-controls are `0x4`

So in total:

```
@LayoutRes final int ZOOM_CONTROL_ID = 0x1;
@LayoutRes final int MY_LOCATION_CONTROL_ID = 0x2;
@LayoutRes final int NAVIGATION_CONTROL_ID = 0x4;
```