# (Android Maps V2) How can we change the alignment of zooming components as +/- buttons in supportMapFragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, supportmapfragment

I'm using the maps V2 by getting support of supportmapfragment.
Is it possible to change the alignment of +/- Buttons for zooming in or out on Google Map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no logical way to do this with the V2 API. It is either enabled or diabled. 
See this link where other SO users have stated this, and you will probably need to setup your own controls if you wanted to move them around:
[Android Maps Library V2 zoom controls custom position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071230/android-maps-library-v2-zoom-controls-custom-position)

Comment: Thanks Android-converter, it is really helpful!