# Reposition Zoom Controls on GoogleMap from SupportMapFragment (not MapView)

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I want to set zoom controls at top right corner of my `GoogleMap` which is from `SupportMapFragment`.

I have found solutions to get `ZoomControls` from `MapView` and add it to required position but the problem is I'm not using `MapView`.

`map.setPadding(leftPadding, topPadding, rightPadding, bottomPadding);` doesn't work for me either as I've other views on my `GoogleMap` which I don't want to be calculated everytime I zoom-in/out when I use `map.setPadding()`.

I've gone through documentations but couldn't find anything useful to this perspective.

**Is there any way to get `ZoomControls` from `GoogleMap` or `SupportMapFragment` ?**

Comment: Please check SO post - [Android Maps Library V2 zoom controls custom position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071230/android-maps-library-v2-zoom-controls-custom-position).

Comment: @Teyam Please check my question.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution which comes to my mind is to remove `GoogleMap`'s `ZoomControls` and add your own zoom controls anywhere you want. In that case you'll have to provide your own + and - controls.

Comment: I doubt if I can add any `View`s to a `GoogleMap`.

Comment: Your choice, but this is not a hack - this is method you use when you want for example give the + and - buttons your app look&feel.